# Dark & bright triangles/faces on exported mesh visible in-game

Tags: mesh, faces, topology

[image: in-game][image: topology]

I'm trying to add more detail to a mesh that already had this problem. There isn't anything in blender that I can see would cause this. I tried manipulating normals but it doesn't seem to affect the issue. Adding a sharp edge along the mirror line removes this but then the shadows look a bit unnatural in-game. Switching to flat shading also helps but looks bad in-game as well. It happens on the axis where the texture gets mirrored. Subdividing along the mirror line makes the effect smaller, corresponding to the smaller face size. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: A line along a mirror edge is often due to an internal face. Look at your object in x-ray mode and delete any internal faces that you find.

Comment: thanks for your comment. there are no internal faces. the texture is mirrored but there is no cut in the topology along the mirror line...